# Tridion 2013 creating a BluePrint structure

Tags: 2013, blueprint

I am trying to create a standard BluePrint structure in Tridion 2013.

I am getting some incredibly weird behaviour

I have created a (001) Master publication with an empty 'root' SG - I would like to add a child to this, so go through the 'Blueprint hierarchy" option on the menu.  It shows :

LEVEL 0 - (001) Master

Adding a child pub from here (002) Schema now shows :

LEVEL 1 - (002) Schema directly underneath.

I can not for the life of me add any further children to this - all the options are greyed out for adding children - going through the 'old' way of right clicking the pub and then going through the Properties / Blueprinting tab to add a new child just opens a popup window which then closes immediately.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only add a BluePrint Parent in the Publication Properties when creating a new Publication.

You can never add Children, that is done by adding a Parent to them (the BluePrint hierarchy view shows you an option of adding a Child, which basically will open that Child Publication and add your current one as a Parent, or when adding a new Child, it will create a new Publication), but a first parent can only be set at creation time of a Publication, if one hasn't been set, that Publication can never be made part of a BluePrint.

Adding additional Parent Publications or Children in the BluePrint Hierachy view can only be done if the Publication you want to add is part of the current BluePrint chain, so it must already have a mutual parent. For the first child of your upmost parent, this means the option to add a parent is available, but if there are no publications in the same level (shown right next to it), the window will close directly again, as there is nothing for you to add.

Comment: There's a possible bug here then, because the Add Child option worked for me the first time after creating the Master and then clicking "Add new child" to add the second level pub - it certainly seems to have screwed everything up now as I cannot add anything at all, parent or children!

Comment: Can I also ask... why bother having the "Add child" function if you can't use it?

Comment: I updated my answer to give more clarity on this (hopefully ;o)

Comment: if the options are not working at all anymore, maybe try clearing your browser cache and reloading the entire CME, could be that your newly added publications are not fully available due to the UI cache.

Comment: It's definitely "borked" - can I drop you a mail with some screenshots to show?

Comment: probably easiest to attach the screenshots to your question, then everybody can see

Comment: Side-note, but Tridion 2011 and 2013 heavily cache items in the GUI, especially Schemas and Blueprint options.  A browser cache refresh is necessary every now and then, especially while playing around with Schema options.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question has been answered now, it may be worth noting that you have add an (empty) Structure Group to the root Publication, before you can then add any child Publications.